# [Python]How to know pose of turtlebot

Tags: ros, python, pose, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !
I want to know the pose of turtlebot (x,y,z, z rotation) respect to the point from which it started.
What is the best way to do that in python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271661/%5Bpython%5Dhow-to-know-pose-of-turtlebot/) by [sabruri1](https://answers.ros.org/users/31357/sabruri1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-27**:
What do you mean by

> respect to the point from which it started

? Are you talking about in some reference frame like `world` or `map`? Or, are you comparing two poses (initial and final)?

**Comment by [sabruri1](https://answers.ros.org/users/31357/sabruri1/) on 2017-09-27**:
My robot starts from a point in the room. I would fix a reference frame in this point. Robot reaches a new point. I want to know x,y coordinates of this point in the initial fixed reference frame and it's orientation. Maybe I can use odom topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

As you suggest in your last message, the best practice for doing that is to use the odom topic. For that, you can create a simple subscriber in Python that gets the data you need, which is, position and orientation respect to an starting point. The code for a simple subscriber could be like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry

def callback(msg):
    print msg.pose.pose

rospy.init_node('check_odometry')
odom_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, callback)
rospy.spin()
```

This code basically subscribes to the odom topic, and prints the pose component of the message, which contains the position and orientation values. I've also created a video with a quick demonstration, which may be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPsrOQrzkaM

---

Originally posted by [Alberto E.](https://answers.ros.org/users/31003/alberto-e./) with karma: 356 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [srnand](https://answers.ros.org/users/34391/srnand/) on 2018-03-29**:
Hi,

this msg.pose.pose.orientation.w, return a value 1 in the initial configuration where everything should be zero.

Can you explain why?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-03-29**:
(0,0,0,1) is the identity quaternion: I'd suggest reading more about quaternions. https://answers.ros.org/question/9981/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them/